# Questions on the usefulness or validity of published signal/image processing techniques

Tags: discussion, on-topic, asking-questions, specific-question

The DSP literature increases steadily with more or less useful papers. Sometime, a potential promising ideas get little notice. It could be that the paper (if not obviously wrong) has not reached its target audience. For instance an algorithm designed for images, with little added value, could make sense in signal. Or possibly  its known applications are poor, or mismatched.

At SE.DSP, there is an audience with wide interests, a lot of applications. While we should avoid opinion-based Q&A:

- would it be interesting to expose an idea from a published source?
- could we ask whether somebody has tried similar stuff, or know types of data for which the idea could be interesting?

While this is not the main business model for SE, this could enrich the overall knowledge and promote collaborations between users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided the information could be posed in a Q&A style format, I think this is OK.  It's perfectly OK to answer your own questions, so this might be one case where this is a good idea.

I know I asked a couple of questions that I intended to answer myself to get things moving on this site... but I received too many good answers --- probably better than my own answer --- so I didn't answer my own questions in the end. :-)

Comment: Here my goal is not to write an answer myself

Comment: @LaurentDuval : No problem, provided you write the question so as to be answerable here.  Some papers are a little high-falutin' for general consumption. :-)

Comment: At least I learned the word 'highfalutin' in the process. Could earn votes at http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @LaurentDuval : I'm already in the top 2% there this quarter. Go figure. :D

Comment: Hey, I am not too far behind

Comment: @LaurentDuval : Very good! Top 3% this year! :-)

Answer (score 1):

The rules appear to allow such questions if you state them the right way. Quoting [Signal Processing Stack Exchange help center](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

> **Some subjective questions are allowed, but “subjective” does not mean
>   “anything goes”. All subjective questions are expected to be
>   constructive.** What does that mean? Constructive subjective questions:
>
> - inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”
> - tend to have long, not short, answers
> - have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone
> - invite sharing experiences over opinions
> - insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references
> - are more than just mindless social fun

Comment: If you can draw a line between what is objective, and what is subjective, I'll be quite interested :)